# Is it a good approach to detect user agent with PHP and then load proper CSS stylesheet?

Tags: php, css, cross-browser, compatibility

As in topic title, I'm working on some project but my CSS works great in Mozilla but in Opera dimensions in px are different.I was trying to fix that using percent dimensions but other issues appears.It's some kind of Opera problem as it recognise CSS code in other way because when inspecting an element, it returns totally different px dimensions of div's and borders for example.My idea to avoid it is to create separate CSS files for specific browsers and choose correct one after checking user agent?Maybe exists shorter way to solve this problem?I need my website displayed correctly in Mozilla,Opera,Chrome.

Comment: I personally would just use css media queries, it will be a lot simpler to manage in the end.

Comment: It's not that what I was looking for.I checked some threads and I guess that my idea isn't bad at all.I want to avoid using libraries, frameworks and other stuff like that.Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While possible, loading a different CSS based on detected browser is not generally considered best practice and **defeats the purpose of CSS**. Before you take that decision:

- consider writing cross-browser compatible CSS:

  - use `em` or `rem` instead of `px` as a `font-size` unit;
  - add browser specific prefixes to properties that require it for added compatibility;
  - use [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS) when in doubt - it's a great tool;
- check out [browser specific selectors](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/)

As a personal note, I have tried this method myself and quickly fell behind updating all required CSS files. I ended up merging them in a single file about one year later and that change alone was harder than expected.